# MATLAB automatically converts double to int without explicit cast

Tags: matlab, casting, int, double

I would let the output speak for itself:

```
>> numFiles, meanTangle, sdTangle

numFiles =

         526


meanTangle =

    0.4405


sdTangle =

    0.1285
```

Now, when I create a vector out of these variables:

```
>> [numFiles meanTangle sdTangle]

ans =

         526           0           0
```

Also, just for clarification:

```
>> class(numFiles)

ans =

int32

>> class(meanTangle)

ans =

double

>> class(sdTangle)

ans =

double
```

Why does MATLAB convert floats (`meanTangle` and `sdTangle`) to int without cast?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It converts all of your doubles to ints because your array contains a single int.  This has to do with a precision issue.

It converts the entire array into type int32:

```
>> class(ans)

ans =

int32
```

Answer (score 4):

For reasons not explained, combining an integer data type in an array with floating point data is defined by MATLAB to return an integer data type.

Check this for more info [Float becomes integer](http://www.mathworks.nl/matlabcentral/answers/36773-why-float-no-become-integer)
.
Your `numFiles` is an integer here so It converts all other variables also as integer.

Comment: even though it's not intuitive, this is a documented behavior. See [Combining Unlike Classes](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/br04cfa-1.html) in the docs.